# How to fill different excel sheets using data entry forms?

Tags: vba, excel

I need to create a Excel solution to record data about a family.

1. The form should generate an unique code (autonumeric) to identify that record. Here, I ask for names, last names and date of births of the parents. This is recorded in a sheet (called `Parents`).
2. A family can contain more than one child, so I thought this has to be recorded on another sheet (called `Children`) keeping the relation to their parents.

I am able to save every different field to its corresponding cell (mapped). Here is the code that I use to get it:

```
Private Sub cmdSave_Click()
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Parents").Activate
Range("B2").Select
Do
If IsEmpty(ActiveCell) = False Then
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
End If
Loop Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell) = True

'Father
ActiveCell.Value = txtFatherFN.Text
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1) = txtFatherSN.Text
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2) = txtFatherLN.Text
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3) = txtFatherBirthDay.Text
'Mother
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4) = txtMotherFN.Text
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 5) = txtMotherSN.Text
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 6) = txtMotherLN.Text
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 7) = txtMotherBirthDay.Text
Range("B2").Select
End Sub
```

So, I need a way to generate a code and keep the relation to the children.
Any help is welcome!

Comment: You have shown us what you have tried for the parents and it looks to work, but what you tried for the child? Please show us what you've tried and failed on, and we can help tweak it.

Answer (score 0):

Okay. Slow day for me. Here is your code written out for you. I also cleaned up your original code a bit to make it more efficient.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub cmdSave_Click()

Dim wks As Worksheet

Set wks = Sheets("Parents")

'assumes headers in First Row, ID is Column A
With wks

    'find next empty row
    Dim lngRow As Long
    lngRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row

    'find next unique Id
    Dim lngID As Long
    lngID = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max("A:A") + 1

    'id
    .Cells(lngRow, 1) = lngID
    'Father
    .Cells(lngRow, 2) = txtFatherFN.Text
    .Cells(lngRow, 3) = txtFatherSN.Text
    .Cells(lngRow, 4) = txtFatherLN.Text
    .Cells(lngRow, 5) = txtFatherBirthDay.Text
    'Mother
    .Cells(lngRow, 6) = txtFatherFN.Text
    .Cells(lngRow, 7) = txtFatherSN.Text
    .Cells(lngRow, 8) = txtFatherLN.Text
    .Cells(lngRow, 9) = txtFatherBirthDay.Text
End With

Set wks = Sheets("Children")

With wks

    'find next empty row
    lngRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row

    'need to adjust the for statement for however you collect your children in your form
    For Each Child In Children 'this is an example only to illustrate. You will need to change Child / Children to the objects used to collect the children info.
        .Cells(lngRow, 1) = Child
        lngRow = lngRow + 1
    Next

End With


End Sub
```